# How to add two integers in one line

Tags: javascript, methods

Hello im new to java and in my class my prof wants us to create a program that will compute the sum of two numbers. (Use methods)
For example:
Input an integer: 95
//Expected Output:
The sum is 14
//(9+5=14)

im really lost on this one because i really don't know how to do this please help

Comment: It's either java or javascript. Fix your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Java you can use this code:

```
int num = 95;
int sum = 0;

while (0 != num) {
    // add the last digit of the given number to the sum
    sum = sum + (num % 10);
    // remove the last digit of the given number
    num = num / 10;
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

(The code in JavaScript is very similar)

Answer (score 2):

From an algorithm point of view, the easiest way would be to:

- convert the integer to a string
- iterate the characters
- convert each character back to an int
- do the sum

In "Modern" java:

```
String.valueOf(test).chars().mapToLong(c -> Long.parseLong("" + (char) c)).reduce(Long::sum).getAsLong()
```

In older java:

```
int test = 95;
long sum = 0;
for (char c : String.valueOf(test).toCharArray()) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

In javascript:

```
let sum = 0
for (let c of String(test)) {
    sum += parseInt(c)
}
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering too but where are not this far in our topic so i cannot use this still thank you

Comment: No problem, good luck with it! (I actually prefer the other answer!)